# jQuery loading data with sticky footer

Tags: jquery, ajax, sticky-footer

I have a sticky footer that I've set up with jQuery and works wonderfully, calculates the height of the window, the height of the content and positions itself at the bottom of the page if there is not enough content to push it down. It also works if the user resizes the browser window.
The problem comes in when the users are editing their profile I load content with AJAX, if the content is just 1 line or 2 then all good, but if it's longer the page extends but the footer doesn't realize.

Is there anyway that the footer can be aware when this happens?
There might be a function that I'm not aware of, anybody has any ideas?

Comment: If you're triggering the Ajax load could you not put an `updateFooter` event in at the same time and have the footer recalculate it's position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on ajax `success:`  after you handle all the ajax code call the function that is used on page load to adjust the size and position of footer